# Monaco-editor : disable command palette

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm creating an electron app using monaco-editor but I want to disable the command palette when I press on F1. I tried e.preventDefault or e.stopPropagation but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/419) from Monaco's repo shows you how you can overwrite the keybinding to do nothing. That stops the command palette from getting opened.

Comment: Could you maybe share the code that you have so far and how you tried to solve it?

Comment: Let me explain. I created my own command palette. When you press on F1, it shows mine but when the editor is on, it also enable monaco-editor command palette.