# How to totally disable the command palette in monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to disable this feature totally, including the ContextMenu and the Keyboard shortcuts.

I see

- [How to hide the "Command Palette" item from the list of actions in Monaco Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597274/how-to-hide-the-command-palette-item-from-the-list-of-actions-in-monaco-editor)
- [Monaco-editor : disable command palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814194/monaco-editor-disable-command-palette)
- [#2619](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2619)
- [#419](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/419)

but seems they are outdated and didn't really DISABLE the feature.